# Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

Refering the [AjaxControlToolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/jquery_ui_mvc_intro.ashx), I created a UI dialog from MVC.

### Layout.cshtml

```html
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
   <link href="../../Content/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
   @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
```

### Index.cshtml

```
<h2>jQuery UI Hello World</h2>          
<button id="show-dialog">Click to see jQuery UI in Action</button>            
<div id="dialog" title="jQuery UI in ASP.NET MVC" >  
  <p>You now have the power of ASP.NET, the simplicity of client-side scripting with jQuery, and the looks of jQuery UI. Congrats, web slinger!</p>  
</div>  

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $('#dialog').dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      width: 600,
      buttons: {
        "Ok": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); },
        "Cancel": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); }
      }
    });
    $("#show-dialog").button().click(function () {
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
  });  
</script>
```

I checked both in IE and Firefox. Firefox throws

> Typeerror $(...).dialog is not a function

IE throws

> Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why is your `Index.cshtml` using the WebForms syntax? What you have shown is an invalid Razor view.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

3 things come to mind that might be worth checking:

1. Never hardcode urls in an ASP.NET MVC application. Always use helpers (or bundles which are recommended):

   ```
   <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8" />
       <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
       <link href="~/Content/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" />
       <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
       <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
       <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
       @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
       @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
   </head>
   ```
2. Make sure that at the end of your `_Layout.cshtml` you don't have a `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` call because this would include jQuery twice.
3. If at the end of your `_Layout.cshtml` you have a dedicated section for custom scripts like `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)`, make sure that you have placed your custom script in that section (notice that since this RenderSection is at the end of the DOM you don't need to be wrapping your script in a document.ready event because by the time it executes, the DOM will already be loaded):

   ```
   <h2>jQuery UI Hello World</h2>          
   <button id="show-dialog">Click to see jQuery UI in Action</button>            
   <div id="dialog" title="jQuery UI in ASP.NET MVC" >  
      <p>You now have the power of ASP.NET, the simplicity of client-side scripting with jQuery, and the looks of jQuery UI. Congrats, web slinger!</p>  
   </div>    

   @section scripts {
       <script type="text/javascript">
           $('#dialog').dialog({
               autoOpen: false,
               width: 600,
               buttons: {
                   "Ok": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); },
                   "Cancel": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); }
               }
           });
           $("#show-dialog").button().click(function () {
               $('#dialog').dialog('open');
               return false;
           });
       });  
       </script>
   }
   ```

Comment: @PankajGarg, I have updated the answer so that you can rollback your downvote.

Comment: I had this issue and found that I had left some "<script src..." tags in a partial view (which were there for testing) - so check everywhere to ensure no duplicated jquery calls. Additionally, a restart of a local instance maybe required to clear any partial view caches.

Answer (score 9):

In my case, this error was because I had forgotten to add the jquery-ui file reference:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

This commonly happens when you forget to add `jquery-ui.js`. The order of including `jquery-ui-{version}.js` also matters!

You should include `jquery-{version}.js` then `jquery-ui-{version}.js`. Then just before `</body>` tag, include your custom javascript file.

It will solve Javascript runtime error: [*Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'*],[*'$' is undefined*]

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the importance of the order - that's what fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems OK to me. You could check that your jQuery UI custom contains dialog feature (or try downloading [full jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/resources/download/jquery-ui-1.10.2.zip) for testing purposes) and check that the URI to the JS script is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Include these three lines of code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```