# Mvc Create button pop up need help C#.net

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating a Create,Edit,Delete application for simple one table. 
I have `Create get method` and `create post method` views ready as i created my project using entity framework.

now in my current application it is opening a new page to create new data and what i want is to open a pop up in which I add required fields and than when I click on ADD it will add those data in database.

**FloorFactorsController.cs**

```
public PartialViewResult Create()
{
    return PartialView();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "FloorFactorPercentage,FromDate,ToDate")] FloorFactor floorFactor)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.FloorFactors.Add(floorFactor);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(floorFactor);
}
```

**Index view.cshtml required part of full code.**`

Here, I have add ajax.actionlink for adding an CREATE NEW link which redirect to my `get method create`in controller class. I have added all required .css and js files i.e. `jquery.js, dialog.js,dialog.css etc.`

```
<p>
   @Ajax.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Get" ,UpdateTargetId = "result", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, OnSuccess = "openPopup" }) <br />
</p>

<div id="result" style="display:none;">
    <button type="button">success</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#result").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Title',
        width: 500,
        height: 'auto',
        modal: true
    });
});
function openPopup() {
    $("#result").dialog("open");
}
</script>
`
```

It Gives error

> Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'

I don't know what to do i have referred this [QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803424/mvc-pop-up-windows)  but this is not working for me.

**EDIT** **_layout.cshtml File**

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="~/Content/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/dialog.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/dialog.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: are you getting proper ajax result in place?

Comment: I am new to ajax can you please tell me how can i make sure that ?  and i can't see any output at this time as it is showing me exception at run time.

Comment: ok no issues, please check it using developer tools by adding a debugger at the `$("#result").dialog("open");` line and check the result div when the debugger hits..:)

Comment: it is not showing any value for div. it shows only **this** & **arguments** in locale box.

Comment: is the ajax getting completed successfully?

Comment: try doing this to debug:`function openPopup() {
    alert($("#result").html());
}`

Comment: yea i also put a breakpoint on ajax link it executes it and than jump directly  on function resides in document.ready field. i think it skips div block. 
Is there any other way to put pop up window where i can put create functionality ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112490/discussion-between-harshil-shah-and-samghatak).

Comment: @HarshilShah What browser is it ?

Comment: @Chintan with your comment i just changed my browser and it dosn't show that error anymore... but still can't see pop up as i expact. It shows View of my create method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after so much surfing on new i found few useful links and got solution to my question.

In order to use jquery-ui files i required to put those files in @Scripts.render(""); as it is best practice to add all script and style files in it for better performance.

I was unable to add @Script & @Styles in my project. It was giving me error that it is not in the context. so this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475893/how-to-add-reference-to-system-web-optimization-for-mvc-3-converted-to-4-app) solved my that problem. than i just pasted link in it and my dialog start working fine. still i am trying to open dialog box using ajax but i did open dialog box using javascript.

Code to open pop up with javascript :

```
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="Name" />
        <input type="text" id="Address" />
        <button onclick="OpenDialog()">
            Open Dialog</button>
    </div>
<div id="Dialog-Box">
        <input type="text" id="Dialog-Name" />
        <input type="text" id="Dialog-Address" />
        <input type="submit" onclick="onsave()" value="save" />
    </div>
    <script>
    $('#Dialog-Box').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 500,
            width: 700,
            modal: false
        });
    function OpenDialog() {

            var name = $('#Name').val();
            var address = $('#Address').val();
            $('#Dialog-Name').val(name);
            $('#Dialog-Address').val(address);
            $('#Dialog-Box').dialog('open');
        }
    function onsave() {

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    name: $('#Dialog-Name').val(),
                    address: $('#Dialog-Address').val()
                },
                success: function (msg) {
                },
                error: function (msg) {
                }
            });

        }
    </script>
```

Thank you everyone for efforts.

Comment: Must visit that link on QUESTION which i attached in order to solve `Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog' error`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't add a comment because my reputation lower than 50. Did you ever read this:
[Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15679715/object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-dialog) 
? I think that you didn't include  jquery file properly.

Comment: yea i checked it just now. Checked all three options but still it is not working. well can you explain what is hardcore urls ? my code does't have @script.render so thats also not the issue.

Comment: Thats not an issue @AirNoir , In that case the the `$(document)` would show `$ is not defined`

Comment: @SamGhatak,  In that post, the author has metioned  "I checked both in IE and Firefox. Firefox throws "Typeerror $(...).dialog is not a function" and IE throws Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'. " , so I thought Harshi Shah might encounter the same problem.

Comment: If you see that post, the user had the issue even after he added a reference to the jQuery library. Did you try using this code without the jQuery library and see if you get similar error? Both the error messages you shown has the issue with `.dialog()` , so it identifies the `$()` meaning it understands jQuery....thus the library is included

Comment: Harshil, he means that don't use <script src="xxx.js"></script> in your Layout.  You should use "@script.render" helper to include the script. By the way, try to put your script section inside the header.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're importing a CDN or downloaded version of jQuery UI that doesn't include the dialog widget.

To test this theory, replace the script reference for jQuery UI with the following:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

I have other questions about what you're actually trying to achieve here, since your controller has `ActionResult` methods instead of `JsonResult` and why you're GETting a request to a method that is decorated with `[HttpPost]`, but that's not what you're asking about in this question.

Comment: Thanks for answer @Phil. Actually i have both Get & post method for create. First i need to show a pop up form to get data from user and than with post request i will store those data in database. Thats why i am using Get request just to display Pop up form. i will use my post method on submit button.  
Now i changed my browser and that dialog error is not coming anymore   so do you know it is browser dependent or not ? dialog is working fine in Crome but not in IE.

Comment: The dialog shouldn't be browser dependent but the versions of jQuery that are supported by older versions of IE will matter. Might help if you posted the code where you have your script references into your original post.